# How to share with access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have write this code but it does work only if I am already logged in facebook, otherwise appears a popup window that require me email and password to login in facebook.

This is the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxx',
        frictionlessRequests: true,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    function update(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function (info) {
                login(response, info);
            });

        } else {

        }
    }

    FB.getLoginStatus(update);
};
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());


function login(response, info) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        publish();
    }
}

function publish() {
    var publish = {
        method: 'feed',
        access_token: '<?php echo $token; ?>',
        message: 'How are you ?',
        name: 'hi friends',
        caption: 'yuhuuuuuuuu',
        description: (' '),
        link: 'http://www.example.com',
        picture: 'http://cdn1.hark.com/images/000/004/514/4514/original.jpg',
        actions: [{
            name: 'Hello',
            link: 'http://www.example.com/'
        }],
        user_message_prompt: 'Share on facebook'
    };

    FB.ui(
    publish, function (response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');

        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `update` method, in the blank `else` you should call the [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method:

> Calling FB.login prompts the user to authenticate your application
>   using the OAuth Dialog.

However, you can't just do this:

```
function update(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        FB.api('/me', function (info) {
        login(response, info);
        });

    } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log("user is logged in!", response.authResponse);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Since as it states in the documentation:

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.

You'll have to show a user a button or something that tells him to click in order to login, and then you can call the `FB.login` method.

Comment: So the user must relogin even if I have the access token ?

Comment: If the user is already logged in and have been authenticated then calling `FB.getLoginStatus` should be enough and it will return the `authResponse` with all the needed info. Otherwise you'll need to call `FB.login`. Also, if you call `FB.login` and the user is already authorized then the popup will immediately close by itself and your callback will be called.

Comment: Ok but the user must first reclick on "login". Is there a way to avoid that ? Thanks :D

Comment: however in this way also works without access token. So, How can I use the access token ?

Comment: No, You should call `FB.getLoginStatus` first which does not require a user action. If the response says the user is not logged in or not authenticated for your app then you need to get the user to click a button which will result in `FB.login`. What access token are you talking about? Where is it coming from?

Comment: I am talking about the access token that I get after calling this: function login(response, info) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; ...

Comment: In most cases you won't need to use the access token directly, when using the `FB` object (like `FB.ui` or `FB.api`) the sdk will add the token to all requests. Only if you are making api requests yourself, without the fb sdk, will you need to use the token yourself.

Comment: So, if I am using js sdk, is the access token useless in my case ? I thought that by using the 'access token, I could make requests even if the user was not logged in facebook.

Comment: If you have a valid access token then yes, you can make requests even if the user is logged out. But you'll need to get the token first, and for that the user must be logged in.

Comment: Ok, I need to make requests when the user is logged out ( I have already get a valid token ). How can I do that? This is what I want to know :D ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12636/discussion-between-nitzan-tomer-and-xrobot)